# FATAL: catalog is missing 1 attribute(s) for relid 2662

Tags: postgresql-9.1, recovery, corruption, disaster-recovery

I have a server with PostgreSQL9.1-903 (Windows 7 Professional). After a power cut my database is inaccessible (I presume that the database is corrupted).

The postgreSQL service starts but the following message is displayed when I try to connect via `pg_Admin`:

> FATAL: catalog is missing 1 attribute(s) for relid 2662

I have tried to disable the option: 'ignore_system_index' but the database is still inaccessible. I guess that is not a problem with the indexes, but with the fact that some rows of the table pg_attribute have disappeared.

I am interested in recovering the data because my last backup is a bit old. Is there any way to just connect to the database? After that I would use the tool `pg_dump` to retrieve the data and mount it in a new database.

**EDIT**

The parameter `fsync` is commented in the `postgresql.conf` (I assume that the default value is `on`). Following, I attach the part of the `postgresql.conf` which has been tuned:

```
checkpoint_segments = 32    # in logfile segments, min 1, 16MB each

shared_buffers = 1GB        # min 128kB

work_mem = 8MB

maintenance_work_mem = 256MB

effective_cache_size=1024MB

default_statistics_target = 200

autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 50ms
```

Comment: Were you running with `fsync=off` by any chance? Please post any modified `postgresql.conf` options. Also, before you do ANYTHING more, make a complete copy of the database directory (including `base`, `pg_xlog`, and all other folders and files) after stopping the database server.

Comment: I also had this problem  _VACUUM FULL_ the db solved my issue as per [this](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/11893.1053643226@sss.pgh.pa.us)

Comment: In my case I remove the postgresql completely and install it again, and it worked (*Warning:* this solution is doable only if you don't care about the data that's allocated in psql)
```sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql-*```
```sudo rm -Rf /etc/postgresql /var/lib/postgresql```
```sudo apt-get install postgresql```

Answer (score 2):

**Upon database corruption, before doing anything else, one should read https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption and take a file system level backup.**

You need to restore from backup or, if backup is missing, check corrupted tables for example

```
select distinct relname 
from pg_class 
where not exists (select 1 from pg_attribute where attrelid = relfilenode)`
```

or

```
select distinct relname 
from pg_class 
where relfilenode > (select max(attrelid) from pg_attribute)
```

And then your need to restore missing record in `pg_attribute` (for example create `simm` table and

```
copy with q as 
( select attname, atttypid, attstattarget, attlen, attnum, attndims, attcacheoff, atttypmod, attbyval, attstorage,attalign, attnotnull, atthasdef, attisdropped, attislocal, attinhcount, attcollation, attacl, attoptions, attfdwoptions 
  from pg_attribute 
  where attrelid::regclass = your_table::regclass) ) 
 INSERT INTO pg_catalog.pg_attribute select [id from your pgclass missing instead new attrelid], * from q
```

Then check, that `atttypid` exists and do `vacuum` on `pg_class` and `pg_attribute`. So, your problem must be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Errors in attributes might be not so critical as they appear to the user. This is because database engines are written presuming strict consistency of each query during processing. But error handling in the database engine could be made more error-tolerant for data rescue purposes.

As a proof of concept I've created patches for PostgreSQL database to return warnings instead of fatal errors for missing attribute or data block corruption: https://github.com/dmikushin/postgres-tolerant Although some files in "/var/lib/postgres/data" were missing due to a disk failure and are replaced with earlier versions or placeholders, this patched PostgreSQL proves the content could still be dumped for recovery.